# Set such that $x \in A \implies x\in B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a littlle confused right now, I'm not sure if this is some sort of trick question, but basically I am given 3 sets: $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $B =\{3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and $C = \{x \in  \mathbb{N} : x \in A \implies x\in B\}$.
I'm supposed to list the elements of $C$. Well at first I thought the set $\{3, 4\}$, but after analyzing it for a little longer I realized that it can also be the set: $\{0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...\}$, so which one is the right answer and why? Thanks!

Comment: The second one is right, because you have to consider when the sentence is vacuously true.

Comment: Just as a technical point, you should explicitly state whether or not you think of $0$ as a natural number (conventions differ).  Apparently you do, of course, but it's good to clarify the point.  Beyond that, your second version is correct.  For any natural number $n\not\in A$, the claim $n\in A\implies n\in B$ is vacuously true.

Comment: The implication $P \implies Q$ is true whenever $P \land Q$ or $\neg P$. In terms of sets, $C = (A \cap B) \cup (\mathbb{N} \backslash A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$. By definition, the statement $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ is true if and only if one of these statements is true:

1. $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. The numbers that satisfy this condition are $3,4$.
2. $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$. The numbers that satisfy this condition are $5,6$.
3. $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$. The numbers that fit this condition are $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Therefore, $C = \{3,4\} \cup \{5,6\} \cup \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $x$ such that $x\notin A$. Then, for this $x$, the statement “$x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$” is true.

Therefore $\mathbb{N}\setminus A\subseteq C$.

For $x\in A$, the statement “$x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$” is true only for $x=3$ or $x=4$.

Hence $C=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The second answer should be correct because if the statement $x\in A$ is not true, then we assume that the statement $x\in A\implies x\in B$ is correct no matter $x\in B$ is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

$x\in A \implies x\in B \iff$ Not $x\in A $ or $x\in B = True$.

Consider the above fact. You just need to choose x that satisfies the condition.

So $C = \mathbb{N}$ \ {1,2}